# VBulletin cannot Connect to MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, vbulletin

I've just moved a forum from BradPPresents.com to BradP.com. May not be SFW.

It's located at [forum.bradp.com](http://forum.bradp.com).

I'm getting a Database connection error, despite being absolutely sure about the username and password of the database.

Here's the VBulletin Configuration file, with the username and password masked.

```
    <?php
    /*======================================================================*\
    || #################################################################### ||
    || # vBulletin 3.6.8 Patch Level 2 - Licence Number VBF7177F80
    || # ---------------------------------------------------------------- # ||
    || # All PHP code in this file is ©2000-2008 Jelsoft Enterprises Ltd. # ||
    || # This file may not be redistributed in whole or significant part. # ||
    || # ---------------- VBULLETIN IS NOT FREE SOFTWARE ---------------- # ||
    || # http://www.vbulletin.com | http://www.vbulletin.com/license.html # ||
    || #################################################################### ||
    \*======================================================================*/

    /*-------------------------------------------------------*\
    | ****** NOTE REGARDING THE VARIABLES IN THIS FILE ****** |
    +---------------------------------------------------------+
    | If you get any errors while attempting to connect to    |
    | MySQL, you will need to email your webhost because we   |
    | cannot tell you the correct values for the variables    |
    | in this file.                                           |
    \*-------------------------------------------------------*/

        //  ****** DATABASE TYPE ******
        //  This is the type of the database server on which your vBulletin database will be located.
        //  Valid options are mysql and mysqli, for slave support add _slave.  Try to use mysqli if you are using PHP 5 and MySQL 4.1+
        // for slave options just append _slave to your preferred database type.
    $config['Database']['dbtype'] = 'mysql';

        //  ****** DATABASE NAME ******
        //  This is the name of the database where your vBulletin will be located.
        //  This must be created by your webhost.
    $config['Database']['dbname'] = 'db28587_bradp_forum';

        //  ****** TABLE PREFIX ******
        //  Prefix that your vBulletin tables have in the database.
    $config['Database']['tableprefix'] = '';

        //  ****** TECHNICAL EMAIL ADDRESS ******
        //  If any database errors occur, they will be emailed to the address specified here.
        //  Leave this blank to not send any emails when there is a database error.
    $config['Database']['technicalemail'] = 'admin@bradp.com';

        //  ****** FORCE EMPTY SQL MODE ******
        // New versions of MySQL (4.1+) have introduced some behaviors that are
        // incompatible with vBulletin. Setting this value to "true" disables those
        // behaviors. You only need to modify this value if vBulletin recommends it.
    $config['Database']['force_sql_mode'] = false;



        //  ****** MASTER DATABASE SERVER NAME AND PORT ******
        //  This is the hostname or IP address and port of the database server.
        //  If you are unsure of what to put here, leave the default values.
    $config['MasterServer']['servername'] = 'localhost';
    $config['MasterServer']['port'] = 3306;

        //  ****** MASTER DATABASE USERNAME & PASSWORD ******
        //  This is the username and password you use to access MySQL.
        //  These must be obtained through your webhost.
    $config['MasterServer']['username'] = 'Masked, verified correct';
    $config['MasterServer']['password'] = 'Masked, verified correct';

        //  ****** MASTER DATABASE PERSISTENT CONNECTIONS ******
        //  This option allows you to turn persistent connections to MySQL on or off.
        //  The difference in performance is negligible for all but the largest boards.
        //  If you are unsure what this should be, leave it off. (0 = off; 1 = on)
    $config['MasterServer']['usepconnect'] = 0;



        //  ****** SLAVE DATABASE CONFIGURATION ******
        //  If you have multiple database backends, this is the information for your slave
        //  server. If you are not 100% sure you need to fill in this information,
        //  do not change any of the values here.
    $config['SlaveServer']['servername'] = '';
    $config['SlaveServer']['port'] = 3306;
    $config['SlaveServer']['username'] = '';
    $config['SlaveServer']['password'] = '';
    $config['SlaveServer']['usepconnect'] = 0;



        //  ****** PATH TO ADMIN & MODERATOR CONTROL PANELS ******
        //  This setting allows you to change the name of the folders that the admin and
        //  moderator control panels reside in. You may wish to do this for security purposes.
        //  Please note that if you change the name of the directory here, you will still need
        //  to manually change the name of the directory on the server.
    $config['Misc']['admincpdir'] = 'admincp';
    $config['Misc']['modcpdir'] = 'modcp';

        //  Prefix that all vBulletin cookies will have
        //  Keep this short and only use numbers and letters, i.e. 1-9 and a-Z
    $config['Misc']['cookieprefix'] = 'bb';

        //  ******** FULL PATH TO FORUMS DIRECTORY ******
        //  On a few systems it may be necessary to input the full path to your forums directory
        //  for vBulletin to function normally. You can ignore this setting unless vBulletin
        //  tells you to fill this in. Do not include a trailing slash!
        //  Example Unix:
        //    $config['Misc']['forumpath'] = '/home/users/public_html/forums';
        //  Example Win32:
        //    $config['Misc']['forumpath'] = 'c:\program files\apache group\apache\htdocs\vb3';
    $config['Misc']['forumpath'] = '';



        //  ****** USERS WITH ADMIN LOG VIEWING PERMISSIONS ******
        //  The users specified here will be allowed to view the admin log in the control panel.
        //  Users must be specified by *ID number* here. To obtain a user's ID number,
        //  view their profile via the control panel. If this is a new installation, leave
        //  the first user created will have a user ID of 1. Seperate each userid with a comma.
    $config['SpecialUsers']['canviewadminlog'] = '1';

        //  ****** USERS WITH ADMIN LOG PRUNING PERMISSIONS ******
        //  The users specified here will be allowed to remove ("prune") entries from the admin
        //  log. See the above entry for more information on the format.
    $config['SpecialUsers']['canpruneadminlog'] = '1';

        //  ****** USERS WITH QUERY RUNNING PERMISSIONS ******
        //  The users specified here will be allowed to run queries from the control panel.
        //  See the above entries for more information on the format.
        //  Please note that the ability to run queries is quite powerful. You may wish
        //  to remove all user IDs from this list for security reasons.
    $config['SpecialUsers']['canrunqueries'] = '';

        //  ****** UNDELETABLE / UNALTERABLE USERS ******
        //  The users specified here will not be deletable or alterable from the control panel by any users.
        //  To specify more than one user, separate userids with commas.
    $config['SpecialUsers']['undeletableusers'] = '';

        //  ****** SUPER ADMINISTRATORS ******
        //  The users specified below will have permission to access the administrator permissions
        //  page, which controls the permissions of other administrators
    $config['SpecialUsers']['superadministrators'] = '1,4,2';

        // ****** DATASTORE CACHE CONFIGURATION *****
        // Here you can configure different methods for caching datastore items.
        // vB_Datastore_Filecache  - for using a cache file
    // $config['Datastore']['class'] = 'vB_Datastore_Filecache';
        // vB_Datastore_Memcached - for using a Memcache server
        // It is also necessary to specify the hostname or IP address and the port the server is listening on
    /*
    $config['Datastore']['class'] = 'vB_Datastore_Memcached';
    $i = 0;
    // First Server
    $i++;
    $config['Misc']['memcacheserver'][$i]       = '127.0.0.1';
    $config['Misc']['memcacheport'][$i]         = 11211;
    $config['Misc']['memcachepersistent'][$i]   = true;
    $config['Misc']['memcacheweight'][$i]       = 1;
    $config['Misc']['memcachetimeout'][$i]      = 1;
    $config['Misc']['memcacheretry_interval'][$i] = 15;
    */
    // ****** The following options are only needed in special cases ******

        //  ****** MySQLI OPTIONS *****
        // When using MySQL 4.1+, MySQLi should be used to connect to the database.
        // If you need to set the default connection charset because your database
        // is using a charset other than latin1, you can set the charset here.
        // If you don't set the charset to be the same as your database, you
        // may receive collation errors.  Ignore this setting unless you
        // are sure you need to use it.
    // $config['Mysqli']['charset'] = 'utf8';

        //  Optionally, PHP can be instructed to set connection parameters by reading from the
        //  file named in 'ini_file'. Please use a full path to the file.
        //  Example:
        //  $config['Mysqli']['ini_file'] = 'c:\program files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1\my.ini';
$config['Mysqli']['ini_file'] = '';

    // Image Processing Options
        // Images that exceed either dimension below will not be resized by vBulletin. If you need to resize larger images, alter these settings.
    $config['Misc']['maxwidth'] = 2592;
    $config['Misc']['maxheight'] = 1944;

    /*======================================================================*\
    || ####################################################################
    || # Downloaded: 00:16, Wed Mar 19th 2008
    || # CVS: $RCSfile$ - $Revision: 16258 $
    || ####################################################################
    \*======================================================================*/
```

Can anyone give me some ideas?
Much appreciated,
Nick

Comment: "I'm getting a Database connection error" - is there ANY chance you could be a bit more specific?

Comment: Not sure, is there a way to check logs?

Comment: "If any database errors occur, they will be emailed to the address specified here." Do u get any emails??

Comment: Yes! Found the error. 
MySQL Error  : Table 'db28587_bradp_forum.datastore' doesn't exist

What does that mean?

Comment: This is probably a question you should be asking your ISP.  I'd guess that you need to create a whole new database for the new doman name. Often hosted services are given network access to only specific database machines.

Comment: I found that the database import was not working successfully. I had to use BigDump and it worked OK after that. Thanks for all of your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error "MySQL Error : Table 'db28587_bradp_forum.datastore' doesn't exist" means that you've successfully connected to the database, but that it's been unable to locate the datastore table.

This probably means that your import of the database has been unsuccessful. If you have command line access to the db (something like phpMyAdmin should also do the trick) you should check first that the database itself exists and then that the various tables that should be there are.

Answer (score 0):

This error message basically isn't saying anything.
Could you provide a more detailed error message (e.g. Apache log)?
One thing you could try: Replace "`localhost`" with "`127.0.0.1`" (yeah, this makes a difference for mysql)